# Converting A Project To An EXE File - VISUAL BASIC - Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, exe

So I've made a visual basic project in Microsoft Visual Studio and want to know how to convert it to an EXE (executable) file.

Can anyone please help?

I've tried to use the procedure that other people said. Open it in Visual Studio, then build it, then to go to the folder of the project and then into the 'bin' folder and then 'debug' and then I have to go through another only folder and I found it. When I ran it in that folder, it worked, but when I moved the EXE file to a differnt location, it wouldn't work.

I was expecting it to work in another folder.

Comment: Are there other files in the folder?  If so, try copying the entire folder and see if that works.  (If not, then the program may be depending on some path relative to where it is running from, so you'll need to debug that.)

Comment: Yes there are other files, but I would like the EXE file to be a stand-alone file in a folder

Comment: You then need to search on what is needed to publish a "self-contained executable" for the version of Visual Basic you're using.  Modern .NET applications do support this concept: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: Any clue what these other files are? It should be obvious that if the app works in a folder with other files and not in a folder without them then the other files are the issue. If you want our help then you need to explain the issue.

Comment: @holtavolt I've tried the stuff that they asked me to do, but it still published it with the other files.

Answer (score 0):

on the build option. choose the build 'Project Name' then after successful build, click on publish. you need to copy all the files from the folder and paste it on your designated director of send a full copy of those file to the target user of the project.
[Sample Files to be seen after publishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pALYP.png)

Comment: Yeah, I might just close this post because it doesn't look very straightforward